# Only local machine is allowed to connect to virtual hosts

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have a server with Ubuntu installed, and for no reason, my virtual hosts decided that they only want connections from the local machine. I can go onto my different sites with their regular domains on the server, but when I try it from my computer, I get no connection and only "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" as an error. When I write my server's IPv4 address, I get into the default site for apache that I have configured.

I have tried to port forward port 80, 443 on my router and added 443 and 80 the Ubuntu firewall. I have also tried to restart both my router and server.

My virtual hosts configs looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomain.nu
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.nu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.nu/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.nu [OR] RewriteCond
%{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.nu RewriteRule ^
https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and I also use certbot to create my SSL certificates.

Comment: Are you behind an enterprise NAT by chance?  If you are then you cannot host a website behind it, since you cannot forward the port, to your device (since you are not the ISP).

Comment: I can forward ports, my virtual hosts worked just fine 2 weeks ago. But now when i ping my domain i only get "Reply from 82.12.34.5: Destination host unreachable".